# Force VHDL to use generic over constant

Tags: vhdl, register-transfer-level

I have some VHDL where a generic is the same name as a constant in an imported package. NCSIM seems to use the value of the constant from the package over the generic.

Rather than rename the generic is there a way I can force the scope to pick up the generic.

Comment: delete the line `use imported_package.all;` - either replace it with specific use clauses `use imported_package.foo;` for items other than the generic, use qualified names `x := imported_package.foo` instead of base names, or keep the use clauses local to where you need them instead of the generic.

Comment: Try using a bit more precise language and consider providing a sample case. I'd expect a generic declaration would already be within an inner declarative region following a context clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identifier can be qualified with package or entity name in order to specify
which of the overlapping identifiers that should be used.  For example with the
code:

```
package pkg is
  constant CONST : integer := 17;
end package;

...

use work.pkg;
use work.pkg.all;

entity mdl is
  generic(
    CONST : integer := 42);
end entity;

architecture sim of mdl is
begin
  process is
  begin
    report "CONST = " & integer'image(CONST);
    report "pkg.CONST = " & integer'image(pkg.CONST);
    report "mdl.CONST = " & integer'image(mdl.CONST);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

The result with ModelSim is:

```
# ** Note: CONST = 42
# ** Note: pkg.CONST = 17
# ** Note: mdl.CONST = 42
```

However, the problem origins from "pollution" of the name space with `use
work.pkg.all`, so a cleaner solution is to avoid pollution in the first place with `use work.pkg`, and then force qualified names for references to identifiers in the package, except if that approach is unpractical.